# I need to display the smallest value per column w/ uneven no. of columns

Tags: java, multiple-columns

```
public class SmallestColumn2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int [][] smallest = new int [][]{{17,70,97,-20},{27,73},{84,80,40,280},{90,98,58,-48,104}};
        System.out.println("Smallest per column");
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
            int least = smallest[0][col];
            for(int r = 0; r < 4; r++){ 
                if (smallest [r][col] < least){
                    least = smallest[r][col];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Column " + col + ":" + least);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your code works and what do you expect?

Comment: It's supposed to display the smallest value per column

Answer (score 0):

I guess it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I would use condition to avoid this:

```
if(col>=smallest[r].length) //continue the loop
    continue;
```

And I would set `least` variable as the highest possible:

```
int least = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

to avoid exception

The whole code

```
public class SmallestColumn2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int [][] smallest = new int [][]{{17,70,97,-20},{27,73},{84,80,40,280},{90,98,58,-48,104}};
        System.out.println("Smallest per column");
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
            int least = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for(int r = 0; r < smallest.length; r++){ 
                if(col>=smallest[r].length) //continue the loop
                    continue;
                if (smallest [r][col] < least){
                    least = smallest[r][col];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Column " + col + ":" + least);
        }
    }
}
```

To make it more dynamic, I rewrite hardcoded 4 to length of the array. Number 5 should be calculated as highest number of lengths of all arrays, not just hardcoded 5

Note: not tested

Comment: run:
Smallest per column
Column 0:17
Column 1:70
Column 2:40
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at SmallestColumn2.main(SmallestColumn2.java:6)
Column 3:-48
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Thanks so much dude! we shouted with joy here xD

Comment: Dude what about for largest per column?

Comment: dude you're the best! can you help me during mondays 2:00 - 5:00 pm philippine time xD